# Program is meant to count how many duplicates are in an array. However, it returns the wrong frequency values

Tags: c++

Normally I would use other methods to fix this program but I am not allowed to use advanced techniques for this project, and so what I have is more or less as far as I'm allowed to go.

So my program is meant to take in an array with 10 numbers and then output how many of each value is in the array. For example, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} is meant to return

5 1

5 2

However, it returns

6 1

4 2

I've made sure that the finalData and Data arrays are holding the proper values.

```
cout << count(data, data + MAX_VALUE, finalData[i+1]) << " " << data[i] << "\n";
```

seems to be outputting the wrong value.

for some reason. I believe the error is in my last function, getResults, more specifically the last for loop. Here is that function.

```
void getResults(int finalData[], int data[])
{
    int temp[MAX_VALUE];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE - 1; i++)

        if (finalData[i] != finalData[i + 1])
            temp[j++] = finalData[i];


    temp[j++] = finalData[MAX_VALUE - 1];


    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        finalData[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        cout << count(data, data + MAX_VALUE, finalData[i+1]) << " " << data[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is my complete code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


void printHeader();
int getData(string);
void getResults(int finalData[], int data[]);

const int MAX_VALUE = 10;

int main(void) 
{

    int countValue = 0;
    int freq = 0;

    printHeader();

    int data[MAX_VALUE] = {};
    int frequency[MAX_VALUE] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter data position " << i + 1 << "\n";
        data[i] = getData("\nPlease enter a valid integer.\n");

    }

    sort(data, data + MAX_VALUE);

    int values[MAX_VALUE] = {};
    int secondData[MAX_VALUE] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        secondData[i] = data[i];
    }
    getResults(data, secondData);

    return 0;
}

void printHeader()
{

}

int getData(string error)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    do
    {
        cin >> userInput;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << error;
        }
    } while (cin.fail());
    return userInput;
}

void getResults(int finalData[], int data[])
{
    int temp[MAX_VALUE];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE - 1; i++)

        if (finalData[i] != finalData[i + 1])
            temp[j++] = finalData[i];


    temp[j++] = finalData[MAX_VALUE - 1];


    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        finalData[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        cout << count(data, data + MAX_VALUE, finalData[i+1]) << " " << data[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Got the right answer. Made the changes I listed at the top as well as the following change to the count function.

```
        cout << count(data, data + MAX_VALUE, finalData[i]) << " " << finalData[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: Please append your questions with the results of your debugging session.  For example, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values in variables?  What are the expected values?

Comment: Please review `std::map`.  You can associate numbers (key field) with their frequencies (value field).

Comment: Rule of thumb:  declare the capacity of the array as a const variable, e.g. `const int MAX_VALUES = 10;`  Use the named variable everywhere you need to use the capacity, such as `for` loops.  One benefit is that if you want to expand the array, you only need to make one change.  In your posted code, you'll need to find every 10, evaluate if it is the capacity, then change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a simple error. When you call *getResults* you pass the same array(pointer) to 2 different parameters. Now when you update **finalData** the unwanted side effect update also **data**(they are the same pointer(with different name). So when you call count will not return the expected result.

To solve this problem you can do a copy  of the input array and give it as second parameter of *getResults(...)* function.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that it worked like that. I'll try to fix it and see if it works.

Comment: Yes when you pass an array as parameter in reality you pass a pointer to the first element of the array. ;)

Comment: I tried your changes. The program still outputs the wrong values. However, now when I put in 5 1's and 5 2's, it outputs "5 1" twice.

Comment: In the last for of getResults you need to substitute the last cout parameter from data to finalData and use the same index of the call to function count. In this way will be' fine.

Comment: Please when you try it, edit the question with the right code and vote up

Comment: Did it, worked! Thanks a lot, really appreciate it.